# oozie-db > why sa.wf_jobs contains only a few rows

Tags: derby, oozie

I am trying to access Oozie's provided derby with `ij`. According to my understanding all the workflow info is stored in table `SA.WF_JOBS`, but when try to select all from table ``SA.WF_JOBS` there are only a few rows even tough actually thousands of workflows are generated already. Anyone has any idea why was it like that?

Comment: I think that database should be `oozie` unless you have changed it while configuring.

Comment: Thanks for your hint :) but why when I tried to search all tables in the system table sys.systables, there is any table starting with oozie....